# In C++ check if std::vector<string> contains a certain value

Tags: c++, vector, std, stdvector

Is there any built in function which tells me that my vector contains a certain element or not
e.g.

```
std::vector<string> v;
v.push_back("abc");
v.push_back("xyz");

if (v.contains("abc")) // I am looking for one such feature, is there any
                       // such function or i need to loop through whole vector?
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507884/what-is-the-nicest-way-to-find-a-specific-string-in-vector

Comment: As of C++11, this question is no longer a duplicate, as `std::any_of` now gives you a specific way to return true if a container CONTAINS a match, instead of using std::find to return a matching element. Thanks to @colddie for the original correct answer to this.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31933118/8781554

Answer (score 235, accepted):

You can use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) as follows:

```
if (std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), "abc") != v.end())
{
  // Element in vector.
}
```

To be able to use `std::find`: `include <algorithm>`.

Comment: And what if the thing I'm trying to search is `argv`, which isn't a vector or an array (I'm trying to see if a certain command line argument option is present in the passed `argv`)? I created a vector containing all the "elements" of `argv` and applied your solution, though I'm not sure how clean that is.

Comment: @jphollowed `std::string const searchStr = "magic";
  auto result = std::find_if(argv + 1, argv + argc, [&](char const * const arg) { return arg == searchStr; });` works. Not as clean and concise though. You'll need at least C++11 for that to compile.

Answer (score 45):

1. If your container only contains unique values, consider using [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) instead. It allows querying of set membership with logarithmic complexity.

   ```
    #include <set>

    std::set<std::string> s;
    s.insert("abc");
    s.insert("xyz");
    if (s.find("abc") != s.end()) { ...
   ```
2. If your vector is kept sorted, use [`std::binary_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search), it offers logarithmic complexity as well.
3. If all else fails, fall back to [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), which is a simple linear search.

Comment: Even better, if you don't need an ordering on the strings, use a `std::tr1::unordered_set<std::string>`, available from `<tr1/unordered_set>` or `<unordered_set>`, which has (almost) constant lookup and query time. With either set or unordered_set you can alternatively say `if (s.count("abc"))`. Don't forget to _accept_ one of the answers.

Comment: All three of these links seem to link to now-archived pages.

Answer (score 24):

In C++11, you can use `std::any_of` instead.

An example to find if there is any zero in the array:

```
std::array<int,3> foo = {0,1,-1};
if ( std::any_of(foo.begin(), foo.end(), [](int i){return i==0;}) )
std::cout << "zero found...";
```

Comment: I find any_of much better than find, because find return an vector iterator to the element, and any_of return a boolean and much more suitable to if cases

Comment: Can you add some more detail? An example of how to use and a link to the documentation.

Comment: @JamieBullock have you seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31933118/8781554)?

Comment: @Xam Thanks. I know how to use `any_of`, I was encouraging colddie to improve the answer

Answer (score 6):

it's in `<algorithm>` and called `std::find`.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/).